# How to Customize Ubuntu into your own custom distribution

Tags: customizer

Originally, I thought I would base my system off of Debian. I soon realized that I wanted to integrate Ubuntu's easy yet powerful desktop functionality into my own distribution. Thus, my OS would be an unofficial branch of the Ubuntu desktop edition (much like Kubuntu and Xubuntu, although they are official). Could you guys (be polite this time) and tell me things I need to know and tools I need to use for this project. I want to make my own OS just based on Ubuntu, thus changing brand names and themes. I also want to include my own "closed source" software that I developed. By the way I'm not distributing to a large group of people just my job, and a few friends and family.

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea if you read the suggested link and come back with questions that address specific issues you may subsequently face.

Comment: You may want to ask a separate question about when you have to rebrand Ubuntu. For your needs, it seems to me that it may not be (legally) necessary to rebrand or retheme anything. I don't know though because there aren't enough details in your question about that. And of course you might choose to perform partial or total rebranding of a customized Ubuntu system for reasons other than trademark requirements.